# How to add summery to tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am newbie to tensorflow. I want to add a scalar summary to my tensorboard. However the value of the variable is different from the what tensorboard shows:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x_scalar = tf.Variable(0.0, name='batch_train_loss') 
first_summary = tf.summary.scalar(name='My_first_scalar_summary', tensor=x_scalar)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./alaki', sess.graph)
    for step in range(10):
        x_scalar = tf.add(x_scalar, tf.convert_to_tensor(4, dtype=tf.float32))
        val , summary = sess.run([x_scalar,first_summary])
        print(step, val)
        writer.add_summary(summary, step)
    print('Done with writing the scalar summary')
```

The output of the print is:

```
0 4.0
1 8.0
2 12.0
3 16.0
4 20.0
5 24.0
6 28.0
7 32.0
8 36.0
9 40.0
```

However tensorboard shows some wierd numbers instead of correct values for the x_scalar.

Comment: `x_scalar = tf.add(x_scalar, tf.convert_to_tensor(4, dtype=tf.float32))` are you forgetting this part? You should expect your summary to be the first printed value - 4, ie 0. tf.add returns a new tensor, and overwriting the name of the old tensor doesn't affect the summary op on the old tensor.

Comment: Thanks for the point that it is going to be a new tensor! If this is the case, when I call sess.run(first_summary), it should always be the fixed original value of 0. right? However, it is generating random numbers in tensorboard. What I am missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure, the code looks like it should just be storing the same value. What numbers are stored in the tensorboard summary?

Comment: @markemus I got it. I had to set the smoothing to 0 to get the real numbers.

Comment: Good job mate :)